# Browser caching with Varnish, Express & Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, express, varnish

I have a simple server side stack with Redis, Node, React and Express. Express takes the request, grabs the data from Redis and passes it on to React.

All of the data is static (only updated once or twice a year), so I installed Varnish to cache the pages rather than rebuild each page every time.

But static css, js and images aren't being cached client side in the browser. How can I do this with the stack I have?

Also - if I tweak some CSS, how can I make it so it checks to see if there is new CSS and grab that. Do I need to put versioning in through querys? Like `foo.css?v=1.0.0`

Thanks

Comment: Browser caching is handled via the `Cache-Control` header. What is your server sending back? How do you know they're not being cached in the browser?